# Having a static "NULL" object in Java?

Tags: java, null

While browsing through some code for a library I'm using, I came across this code snippet:

```
public class SomeClass {

     private static final class Null {
        /* ... */
     }

     public static final Object NULL = new Null();

}
```

Is this a common practice to have a special NULL object for a class that gets used instead of Java's `null`?  What are the upsides to doing this instead of using Java's built in `null`?

The main reason I'm curious is that while using the library, I kept checking whether SomeClass was null, without realizing that they were using a special NULL object to denote a null object of SomeClass.

**EDIT:** For those wondering, the exact code from the source is:

```
public class JSONObject {
     private static final class Null {
        protected final Object clone() {
            return this;
        }
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            return object == null || object == this;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "null";
        }
    }

    public static final Object NULL = new Null();
}
```

Comment: How is it used?  There is the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), but that primarily makes sense for an class which actually has some user-defined methods.

Comment: @MarkPeters: Whenever a null object would be expected, SomeClass.NULL is passed instead.  In this case, the would-be object is called JSONObject and is used to denote whenever there is a null JSON value.

Comment: But you're obviously paraphrasing here...are you sure the real code's `Null` class wasn't a subclass of some other class, or an implementer of an interface?

Comment: The code within `SomeClass` was left unchanged.  `public static final Object NULL = new Null();` and `private static final class Null {` are the exact lines found in the source.

Comment: I would assume [this](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) is the class/library?  The comment on that field is very vague: *"It is sometimes more convenient and less ambiguous to have a NULL object than to use Java's null value."*  Either way, this starts to make a bit of sense seeing as this is primarily a serialization library.

Comment: `equals` returning true for null looks slippery to me. ["No object is equal to null"](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) can occasionally be a useful one - so you don't use a null reference, but have an actual object with neutral behaviour. However, the implementation you've given there doesn't make sense:

- `Null` doesn't extend SomeClass, which I'd expect it to
- `NULL` is declared as `Object`, not `SomeClass`.

So as it is, I'd say that code is useless. But when implemented properly, the pattern can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "null object pattern". The advantage is that you don't have to explicitly check for null, avoiding NPEs.

Comment: That doesn't help if you're explicitly checking against this single object though...typically the "null object" would be declared in a variable of some specific type.  You wouldn't just have a "Null" class.

Comment: @MarkPeters Partially agreed; I don't get this implementation, but it still avoids NPEs. That said, we can't see the implementation, so I'm not comfortable saying too much about it.

Comment: Yeah, checking for `NULL` is a huge improvement from checking for `null`. I mean, it's written in CAPS, so of course it's huge!

Comment: I misread what you had written. In any case, the NULL in the given code offers only the functionality of `Object`. I don't think that warrents the null object pattern. (Hey! that's NOP!)

Comment: @trinthis Agreed, this is a bizarre pseudo-implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A better name for their class would have been `Empty` or similar. Using variant of java keywords is not a good idea - it leads to confusion... and questions like these.

Also, usually the empty object is a special instance of the class:

```
public class SomeClass {

     public static final SomeClass EMPTY = new SomeClass("parameters that make it empty");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on usage.  There can be NULL classes which, for example, represents a Null data type which is NOT the same as a null in java.  An example is here: http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/Null.html

Otherwise, it would not be idiomatic java to wrap a null value in a NULL object.

Answer (score 1):

[Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

I have used it once on of my projects and wouldn't do that again, because it be tricky when it comes to **serialization**